# Why am I still getting an "inaccessible due to its protection level" error?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls

I am creating a mobile ordering application using a WinForm with multiple User Controls for the different item pages. I am having trouble making my cartList which stores added items and my TeaItem class accessible from other pages. I have looked around and found different solutions but nothing has worked. Right now, I have a class added separately in the project for my cartList and my TeaItem. (This is for a tea shop)

This is my code for the "add to cart" User Control: ("AddMenu.cs")

```
public partial class AddMenu : UserControl
{
    public AddMenu()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    public void addToCart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GlobalCartList.cartList.Add(new TeaItem() { teaName = addTeaNameLabel, teaSize = addSizeComboBox.SelectedItem });
            # cartList, teaName, and teaSize give me the inaccessible errors
    }

    # more code
}
```

Separate class for cart list: ("GlobalCartList.cs")

```
public class GlobalCartList
{
        List<TeaItem> cartList = new List<TeaItem>();
}
```

And tea item: ("TeaItem.cs")

```
public class TeaItem
{
    string teaName;
    string teaSize;
}
```

Can anyone tell why I am still getting this error?

Comment: Use `Public` for your variables. They're all private.

Comment: All the 3 members that you are accessing (i.e. teaName, teaSize and cartList) are private members. If you want to access them directly, you should either make them public members or public properties (recommended with private set). Also cartList should be accessed using an object and directly via the class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to get the cardlist like it is static but it is actualy a non static member of the `GlobalCartList` class:

Secondly you are trying to get it like it is a public member but the `cardlist` is private.

```
  // Here you try to access like it is an static public member.
  GlobalCartList.cartList.Add(...)
```

To call the `cardlist` you have to make it public so it can be called outside the `GlobalCartList` class. Second you have to make the `cardlist` static so you can call it without making an instance of the `GlobalCartList` class.

```
public class GlobalCartList
{
    public static List<TeaItem> cartList = new List<TeaItem>();
}
```

And the is goes for the `TeaItem` make it members public:

```
 public class TeaItem
 {
    public string teaName;
    public string teaSize;
 }
```

> Note that by defautlt if not specified `public` infront of an member
>   the member is `private` and that by default the members of an class
>   are `none static`.

Comment: Thank you so much that worked! Can't believe it was that simple

Answer (score 0):

This is becauese `List<TeaItem> cartList` is private by default. You should add public (or internal) access modifier. 
And probably it should be static, because you don't instatiate GlobalCartList class.

```
public class GlobalCartList
{
    public static List<TeaItem> cartList = new List<TeaItem>();
}
```